# How to pause Dragon Age Inquisition on PC?

Tags: pc, dragon-age-inquisition

I'm looking for a way to really pause Dragon Age Inquisition, in such a way that the time elapsed doesn't change (the one displayed next to the saved games).

I've tried various things - opening the menu, Alt-Tab to the desktop, etc., but the elapsed time keeps changing. Any idea how to do this (assuming it can be done)?

Comment: Can you do this on console?

Comment: You can try changing the clock on your computer. This is assuming the game gets the time from your computer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saved game times are just telling you how long that save has been run in real-life time. Unless you find a way to pause Time Itself outside the game (or I guess binary patch the game executable to count time elapsed differently), you can't stop the game from counting real time elapsed.

If you really don't want the savegame real-life clock to advance, save and quit instead of pausing.